# SQL: find the maximum of period separated version

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 which contains Resource IDs and corresponding versions of a certain file:

```
ResourceID    FileVersion
1             8.00.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
1             11.00.9600.16428 (winblue_gdr.131013-1700)
1             11.00.9600.17041 (winblue_gdr.140305-1710)
1             11.00.9600.17126 (winblue_gdr_escrow.140529-2055)
2             8.00.7601.18472 (win7SP1_GDR_escrow.140527-0630)
2             8.00.7601.22686 (win7SP1_LDR_escrow.140527-0630)
2             11.00.9600.17239 (winblue_gdr.140724-2228)
2             11.00.9600.17420 (winblue_r4.141105-1535)
2             11.00.9600.17496 (winblue_r5.141121-1500)
```

I want to find the maximum version of each Resource ID. The desired output in this case would be

```
ResourceID    FileVersion
1             11.00.9600.17126 (winblue_gdr_escrow.140529-2055)
2             11.00.9600.17496 (winblue_r5.141121-1500)
```

I have tried the following code:

```
Select ResourceID, MAX(SUBSTRING(FileVersion,1,CHARINDEX(' ',FileVersion + ' ')-1))
From VersionTable
Group By ResourceID
```

But get the following output:

```
ResourceID    FileVersion
1             8.00.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
2             8.00.7601.22686 (win7SP1_LDR_escrow.140527-0630)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What type is FileVersion? Your query gives the expected output when I tested here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6600f/1

Comment: Or try ROW_NUMBER() OVER()

Comment: @jpw I am actually parsing FileVersion using the SUBSTRING function. Not sure if this would affect the results.

Comment: @PhilGabardo It might, maybe you could post the relevant part of the complete query?

Comment: @jpw will do, one sec.

Comment: @PhilGabardo This is odd, my SQL Fiddle still gives the correct result: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8afba/2 Can you check if I got the test right?

Comment: Everything appears to be correct, this is really strange. I put in dummy values for the FileVersion for privacy sake, but this may be affecting the query. I'll edit the question with the real values.

Comment: @PhilGabardo is there really a big difference between the real data and the fake data you have placed here?

Comment: Does your table not have any other columns? for instance an id or created date that could be used to determine order of creation?

Comment: Have you considered adding computed column or columns into the table that would contain the version number in a format that can be sorted reliably? Handling strings that contain numeric data can cause surprises when numbers are over 10.

Comment: The edit revealed exactly what happens when sorted in alphabetical order, 8 is bigger than 11.

Comment: @WorkSmarter the data is updated so you can decide for yourself.

Comment: @JamesZ how can I take the max of the integer value as opposed to the alphabetic value?

Comment: @Tanner, no there are no other columns that have data that is reliable enough to determine order of creation. Good idea though.

Comment: @PhilGabardo you can do a cast to integer

Comment: @CiucaS no he can't as some parts may have 3 or 4 digits that would make the integers bigger and there's other data in the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the sort working, you basically have few options:

1) Add computed column or columns to the table, maybe one for each of the groups of numbers or maybe one bigint. Having 4 separate columns is probably safer option.

2) Add 4-part string split to the select, which converts each of the parts separated by period into a number and sort the data as integers. If you have similar logic in several places then you'll end up copy-pasting the same code all over the place.

3) Create a user defined function that returns 4 numbers from the version string. Easy to use in several places, but can cause performance overhead.

4) Create a view on top of the table that creates the version integers. Basically the same thing as function, and not the best thing if there's a lot of rows (or called really often).

Edit: Added idea for a view.

Edit 2: Added example for the select:

```
select
  ResourceID,
  ver
from (
  select
    ResourceID,
    v.ver,
    row_number() over (partition by ResourceID 
        order by n.v1 desc, n.v2 desc, n.v3 desc, n.v4 desc) as rn
  from VersionTable
  cross apply (
    select left(FileVersion, charindex(' ', FileVersion)-1) as ver
  ) as v
  cross apply (
    select charindex('.', v.ver) as p
  ) as p1
  cross apply (
     select charindex('.', v.ver, p1.p+1) as p
  ) as p2
  cross apply (
     select charindex('.', v.ver, p2.p+1) as p
  ) as p3
  cross apply (
    select 
      convert(int, left(v.ver, p1.p - 1)) as v1,
      convert(int, substring(v.ver, p1.p+1, p2.p-p1.p-1)) as v2,
      convert(int, substring(v.ver, p2.p+1, p3.p-p2.p-1)) as v3,
      convert(int, substring(v.ver, p3.p+1, 999)) as v4
  ) as n
) tmp
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks JamesZ, I'll give each of the options a try and let you know if any of them work.

Comment: Added an example query. Looks quite awful to be honest, but didn't figure out how to make it smaller -- and that doesn't even have any error handling

Comment: Thanks a lot JamesZ, this really helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack and might not work always, but it did for your sample data and should give you an idea what you could do:

```
Select 
    ResourceID, 
    max(
       case 
          when charindex('.', fileversion, 0) = 2 
          then STUFF(LEFT(FileVersion, CHARINDEX(' ', FileVersion,0)-1), 1, 1, '0'+left(fileversion, 1))
       else LEFT(FileVersion, CHARINDEX(' ', FileVersion,0)-1) 
       end
       )
From VersionTable
group by ResourceID
```

What it does is to insert a 0 if the first number is 0-9 making it 00-09 which changes the lexical order.

Answer (score 0):

In case you know you will always have the FileVersion table like `number.number.number.number`

This code will work. Basically it creats 4 integers for each part of the version and orders by each one of them starting from the left side ( the number with the higher importance )

```
SELECT * FROM VersionTable
    ORDER BY substring([FileVersion],0,charindex('.',[FileVersion])) DESC,
    substring(substring([FileVersion],charindex('.',[FileVersion])+1,LEN([FileVersion])),0,charindex('.',substring([FileVersion],charindex('.',[FileVersion])+1,LEN([FileVersion])))) DESC,
    substring(substring(substring([FileVersion],charindex('.',[FileVersion])+1,LEN([FileVersion])),charindex('.',substring([FileVersion],charindex('.',[FileVersion])+1,LEN([FileVersion])))+1,LEN(substring([FileVersion],charindex('.',[FileVersion])+1,LEN([FileVersion]))))
    ,0,charindex('.',substring(substring([FileVersion],charindex('.',[FileVersion])+1,LEN([FileVersion])),charindex('.',substring([FileVersion],charindex('.',[FileVersion])+1,LEN([FileVersion])))+1,LEN(substring([FileVersion],charindex('.',[FileVersion])+1,LEN([FileVersion])))))),

    reverse(substring(reverse([FileVersion]), 0 , charindex('.',reverse([FileVersion])))) DESC
```

This will order your table values only not selecting one for each Resource.

Comment: You could save yourself a lot of SUBSTRING()s by using PARSENAME()

Comment: It's not something that comes in handy often, but when it does, it REALLY does.